# Ruptela Eco4+ Device Docs not available

Tags: gps

I am using Ruptela Device for GPS tracking. It is working fine and i am getting data from device to server in form of hexadecimal as follows:

03d30003106796f910bb01011659ae6f4100002e0f9f6711028ac208db00000500001307030500b0000200021d35bb160010
014d000000000059ae6f4200002e0f9f6711028ac208db00000500001305030501b0000200021d35c6160016014d000000000059ae6f4a00002e0f9f6711028ac208db0000050000130703
0501b0000200021d35b7160010014d000000000059ae6f5400002e0f9f6711028ac208db00000500001307030501b0000200021d35be160010014d000000000059ae6f5e00002e0f9f7811
028ac208de00000500001307030501b0000200021d3562160010014d000000000059ae6f6800002e0fa08211028a9008b5805c0500001307030501b0010200021d3603160010014d000000
020059ae6f7200002e0fa01e11028ad308d3805c0500001307030501b0000200021d35df16000f014d000000000059ae6f7c00002e0f9ffd11028bcd08d3805c0500001307030501b00002
00021d35e9160010014d000000000059ae6f8600002e0f9f6711028b5808ca600e0600000c07030501b0010200021d35a8160010014d000000000059ae6f9000002e0f9e8e11028a1c08bc
60c20600000c07030501b0000200021d35b1160010014d000000010059ae6f9a00002e0f9e3b110289ea08c4639c0600000c07030501b0000200021d3577160010014d000000010059ae6f
a400002e0f9dc6110289b808bc58ac0600021307030501b0000200021d3597160010014d000000000059ae6fae00002e0f9dd7110289fa08a9541a0700000b07030501b0000200021d35ba
160010014d000000000059ae6fb800002e0f9db611028a2c08a07ddc0700000b07030501b0000200021d35b1160010014d000000000059ae6fc200002e0f9d7311028a80089f533e070000
0b07030501b0000200021d35bd160010014d000000020059ae6fcc00002e0f9c9a11028986089162e80600001307030501b0000200021d35c0160010014d000000020059ae6fd600002e0f
9c791102888c088762e80700000b07030501b0000200021d35c5160010014d000000000059ae6fe000002e0f9cbc110288f0088d62e80700000b07030501b0000200021d353b16000e014d
000000000059ae6fea00002e0f9cee11028954088c62e80700000b07030501b0000200021d3591160010014d000000000059ae6ff400002e0f9cbc11028975088b62e80700000b07030501
b0000200021d35bc160010014d000000000059ae6ffe00002e0f9c4711028996088d62e80700000b07030501b0000200021d35ad16000d014d000000000059ae700800002e0f9cfe11028a
5e088d62e80800000b07030501b0000200021d35a4160010014d0000000000eb34

Now the main issue is How to decode this data,
Is there some docs to decode the Data into human readable form.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not too late with the answer.

Recently, I've developed a Node.js module that will translate this data of yours into a readable JS object. You can install the package via npm, using the following command:

```
npm i --save ruptela
```

For more details, see the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ruptela

Here is your data as JS object:

```
{
    data: {
        packet_length: 979,
        imei: 862462030713019,
        command_id: 1,
        payload: {
            records_left: 1,
            records_total: 22,
            records: [{
                    timestamp: 1504603969,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775783,
                    latitude: 285379266,
                    altitude: 2267,
                    angle: 0,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 0,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13755,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504603970,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775783,
                    latitude: 285379266,
                    altitude: 2267,
                    angle: 0,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 5,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 22,
                        '29': 13766,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504603978,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775783,
                    latitude: 285379266,
                    altitude: 2267,
                    angle: 0,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13751,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504603988,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775783,
                    latitude: 285379266,
                    altitude: 2267,
                    angle: 0,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13758,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504603998,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775800,
                    latitude: 285379266,
                    altitude: 2270,
                    angle: 0,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13666,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604008,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772776066,
                    latitude: 285379216,
                    altitude: 2229,
                    angle: 32860,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13827,
                        '77': 2,
                        '176': 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604018,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775966,
                    latitude: 285379283,
                    altitude: 2259,
                    angle: 32860,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 15,
                        '29': 13791,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604028,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775933,
                    latitude: 285379533,
                    altitude: 2259,
                    angle: 32860,
                    satellites: 5,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13801,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604038,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775783,
                    latitude: 285379416,
                    altitude: 2250,
                    angle: 24590,
                    satellites: 6,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 12,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13736,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604048,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775566,
                    latitude: 285379100,
                    altitude: 2236,
                    angle: 24770,
                    satellites: 6,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 12,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13745,
                        '77': 1,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604058,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775483,
                    latitude: 285379050,
                    altitude: 2244,
                    angle: 25500,
                    satellites: 6,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 12,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13687,
                        '77': 1,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604068,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775366,
                    latitude: 285379000,
                    altitude: 2236,
                    angle: 22700,
                    satellites: 6,
                    speed: 2,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13719,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604078,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775383,
                    latitude: 285379066,
                    altitude: 2217,
                    angle: 21530,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13754,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604088,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775350,
                    latitude: 285379116,
                    altitude: 2208,
                    angle: 32220,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13745,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604098,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775283,
                    latitude: 285379200,
                    altitude: 2207,
                    angle: 21310,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13757,
                        '77': 2,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604108,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775066,
                    latitude: 285378950,
                    altitude: 2193,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 6,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 19,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13760,
                        '77': 2,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604118,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775033,
                    latitude: 285378700,
                    altitude: 2183,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13765,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604128,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775100,
                    latitude: 285378800,
                    altitude: 2189,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 14,
                        '29': 13627,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604138,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775150,
                    latitude: 285378900,
                    altitude: 2188,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13713,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604148,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775100,
                    latitude: 285378933,
                    altitude: 2187,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13756,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604158,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772774983,
                    latitude: 285378966,
                    altitude: 2189,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 7,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 13,
                        '29': 13741,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    timestamp: 1504604168,
                    timestamp_extension: 0,
                    priority: 0,
                    longitude: 772775166,
                    latitude: 285379166,
                    altitude: 2189,
                    angle: 25320,
                    satellites: 8,
                    speed: 0,
                    hdop: 11,
                    event_id: 7,
                    io: {
                        '2': 0,
                        '5': 1,
                        '22': 16,
                        '29': 13732,
                        '77': 0,
                        '176': 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        crc: 60212
    },
    ack: < Buffer 00 02 64 01 13 bc >
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for replying,but i need to do all this in C#.